# Creating a File-Like Object from email.message.Message

Tags: python

I have an attachment in my `email.message.Message`.

The attachment is of type `email.message.Message` so I can call `get_payload()` on it to return its associated data.

However, I want to be able to load this data into a file-like object so I can read and write from it as if I was reading this attachment from my desktop.

How can I do this without actually saving the attachment on my drive?

Comment: Is this Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: This is for Python 2.x, but thanks for the comment below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cStringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) was made specifically for this purpose.

You can use `StringIO` if you need multiple encoding schemes,but cStringIO is MUCH faster.

Example usage:

```
import cStringIO

test = cStringIO.StringIO()
test.write("test")
test.getvalue()
>>> "test"
```

Comment: Since the OP didn't specify 2.x vs. 3.x, it may be better to say `io.StringIO` in 3.x, `cStringIO.StringIO` in 2.x (and not even mention the `StringIO` module, or `BytesIO`, or any of the other details that are specific to one version or the other). But otherwise, good answer.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to work for strings. However, is there any way to retain the encoding for say an image attachment? Do I need to write more than the payload into the StringIO?

Comment: @user1431282: The `StringIO` will have exactly the same binary data as the `str` you construct it from or `write` into it. If you want to pass out-of-band metadata (like a filename with an extension, or a MIME type), you have to pass it out-of-band, just as you would with a file object representing a real on-disk file.